# Single sign on with OpenIdConnect in .net core - redirect URL

Tags: single-sign-on, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.0, openid-connect

I am using SSO against Azure AD in my .net core application. Used OpenIdConnect for authentication.

Currently after login it is redirected the home page. But I want to redirect it to the specific controller which user clicks before login.

If mysite.com is my site and if user clicks on mysite.com/help it should be redirected to help page after sso.

If user clicks on mysite.com/forum, after sso it should be redirected to forum page.

How to achieve this?

Comment: What you want is actually the default behavior of the OpenId Connect handler. It stores the local path in state and does a second redirect after the user is redirected back to the app. Could you show your code? Especially how you configured authentication, and how you specified the `[Authorize]` attribute.

Comment: Hi, @juunas . I'm not aware of this. Do you mean that use `BuildRedirectUri` mehod in `AuthenticationHandler`?

Comment: In ASP.NET Core, if you setup OpenID Connect authentication, it will by default redirect the user to the page they tried to access. There is no configuration needed actually.

Comment: @juunas sum up your comments as an answer to be able to vote and accept.

Comment: Well, I'm assuming that OP has tried something and it does not work, so my comments may not directly answer the question. I would like to see how it is configured.